# Force https and www to non www through htaccess in any URL of the host

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Through this code in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.muscleshop\.mx [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://muscleshop.mx/.(.*) [L,R=301]
```

I've been able to force https and www to non www but with URL's like this: http://www.muscleshop.mx/productos/acidos-grasos-esenciales the code redirects to home page. I really would appreciate any advice to achieve forcing https and www to non www in ANY URL of the host. Thank you.

Comment: `https://muscleshop.mx/.(.*)` is nonsense. Go read the docs on how back references to parts of what your search pattern matched work.

Comment: @CBroe You're right I've already fixed that line to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://muscleshop.mx/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Then you probably have more RewriteRules than the ones shown?

Comment: @CBroe ... thank you for your last comment ... after I read it I checked all the code in my .htaccess file and realized that I had another RewriteRule so I just move my code just below the first RewriteRule and now everything is working great. Thank you again :)